# How to save webservice call and use it when internet connection available in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire

I m trying to implement webservice call, when user takes screenshot, and I have successfully implemented it with the bellow method.

```
  //this method get called when screenshot captured
func detectScreenShot()  {
    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: mainQueue,
                                           using: { notification in
                                            WEBSERVICE_INTERFACE.webServiceWithPostJSONParameters(param: nil, methodName: Constants.URLs.screenshot, headers: Constants.Headers.urlEncoded, showProgress: false, completion: { (response) in

                                                if let response = response{
                                                    let response = BaseResponse(JSONString : response)
                                                    if let message = response?.message{
                                                        LIMITUtils.showAlertMessage(message: message)
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            })

    })
}
```

But now I have the scenario, suppose user takes the screenshot by making internet connection off, then no webservice call will happen and user will get the benefits out of it. Now I wanted to have some sort of solution where I can save the webservice call if no connection is available and make the same call when internet connection becomes available. Can anyone please suggest me how I can proceed for this?

Comment: If you were uploading the image by capturing the window yourself OR if you were sending the name of the screen where the user took a snap shot you could probably save them some where (user defaults/archive/coredata) and when internet is available you can queue them again. But looking at your code you are just triggering an API without any parameters, so what do you intend to do with this API would probably answer your question.

Comment: @GoodSp33d I just wanted to cut the user credits when I will call the API, But if the internet connection not available then, it will not happen and user will get benifit

Comment: @AkshaykumarMaldhure Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for check Internet available or not  write bellow code to check internet

```
//MARK:- check internet connection
    func checkInternetStatus() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(_:)), name:ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            //Check for Internet Status
            do {
                self.reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
                try self.reachability?.startNotifier()
            } catch {
                jprint("Errore")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func reachabilityChanged(note:NSNotification) {
        let Status = reachability?.currentReachabilityStatus  //note.object as! Reachability
        if Status != .NotReachable  {
            jprint("isNetworkAvailable = true")
            isNetworkAvailable = true
        } else {
            jprint("isNetworkAvailable = false")
            ShowFlinntAlert("No internet", description: "Your internet connection seems to be down")
            isNetworkAvailable = false
        }
    }
```

Before  API call  just check

```
guard isInternetAvailable() else {
    return
}
```

Comment: I know Reachability, But  wanted to save webservice call if no internet connection is available, but Thanks